# Laravel - validar campos

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

tengo un método para crear un registro y la url la llamo asi mediante postman

http://localhost:8080/api/forms?name=1&company_id=1&enabled=1

El código del método es este

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'company_id' => 'required|integer',
        'enabled' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    $input = $request->all();

    $form = Form::create($input);

    return response()->json($form);
}
```

El error que me da es el siguiente

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' 
doesn't have a default value 
(SQL: insert into `forms` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (2020-08-22 14:32:45, 2020-08-22 14:32:45))
```

La ruta la tengo de esta forma

```
Route::post('forms','Api\FormController@create');
```

**Modelo Form**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Form extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [''];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [''];

}
```

Tengo la sensación como si no estoy recogiendo bien los parámetros del request...pero entonces me tendria que saltar el validator no?

Gracias

Comment: Noe compartes tu modelo Form?

Comment: Lo adjunto en el post principal. Gracias @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error proviene de que al tratar de hacer esto:

```
Form::create($input)
```

Antes debes indicar en el modelo que propiedades serán susceptibles de asignación masiva [la cual es una medida de protección de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)   , lo cual consigues indicándolas en la propiedad fillable dentro de tu modelo `Form`:

```
protected $fillable = ['propiedad1', 'propiedad2', ......, 'propiedadN'];
```

Este paso lo debes llevar a cabo por qué usas el método create, si por el contrario crearas una instancia de Form y luego al final ocuparas el método save no sería necesario.

Comment: Vale gracias, que error más básico....1000 gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Por cierto que versión de Laravel usas?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba colocando en tu modelo los atributos

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Form extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];//Todos los atributos que esten en tu tabla excepto created_at y updated_at

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [''];

}
```

Recuerda que en el modelo en laravel tu le debes especificar que atributos tiene tu tabla, tal ves por eso no te lo esta reconociendo , de no ser así revisa en post mas que si este nombrado correctamente el campo de tu formulario y el método por que la validación es correcta.

Comment: Vale gracias, si quiero que sean todos los campos asignables...debo poner '*' y en guarded los que no verdad? como por ejemplo el created_at no?

Comment: Si deseas agregar el campo `created_at` en tu modelo debes asignarlo de esta manera `public $timestamps = true;`